# How take last object property recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a list which is type Classes. Classes object includes 3 property (index, name, classes). Subclasses also contains index, name, classes etc. What I want to do is get the index value of the last classes object. I have written some codes. I can get index value of last object, but then return value of the method is changing null value. How to solve that?

```java
    public Long getClasses (List<Classes> classes){
        Long index=null;

        for(int i=0;i <classes.size(); i++) {
            if(classes.get(i).classes().size()>0) {
                getClasses(classes.get(i).getClasses());
            }
            else {
              index= classes.get(i).getIndexValue();
              break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code when `getClasses` is called repressively you are not returning value coming from upcoming calls of method. Replace your code as below:

```
    public Long getClasses (List<Classes> classes){


            for(int i=0;i <classes.size(); i++){
                if(classes.get(i).classes().size()>0){
                    //Change is here
                    return getClasses(classes.get(i).getClasses());
                }else{
                  return classes.get(i).getIndexValue();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What you are getting? Can you share your Classes and test data and expected output?

Comment: I expect getting indexValue of last object.Method should return indexValue of last object.

Comment: Suppose input list is a with 3 elements. First element has 2 another elements, second has 1 element and third has 4 elements. So what should be return index?

Comment: your code is running properly but compiler says missing return statement